# How to extract unique initials

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe with skill names, I want to extract unique initials for these skills

```
Skill_name             Initials
Risk Management        RM
Scope Management       SM
Stakeholder Management StM
```

I tried regular expressions but it gives me SM in both cases.
Any ideas?

Comment: Why is there `t` in `StM` ?

Comment: because I want unique values

Comment: And what are rules for those initials? In our company, when 2 letters are not sufficient, they take the last character of the last word first, thus `SMt`, not `StM`. How many of these names do you have? If you have 200.000 items starting with S and M, there will not be much room

Comment: I was thinking about first two letters. There are just few of them. Could you share with me your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest iterating through the names like the snippet below, and saving all the existing initials in a set:

```
all_names = [
    'Risk Management',
    'Scope Management',
    'Stakeholder Management',
]
seen = set()
def find_initials(name, seen):
    first, last = name.split()
    for i in range(1, len(last)+1):
        for j in range(1, len(first) + 1):
            initials = first[:j] + last[:i]
            if initials not in seen:
                seen.add(initials)
                return initials
    # full name is found in seen!
    for i in range(100):
        initials = f'{first}{last}{i}'
        if initials not in seen:
            seen.add(initials)
            return initials

initials = [find_initials(name, seen) for name in all_names]
print(initials) # ['RM', 'SM', 'StM']
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution

```
unique = list()
def unique_initials(full_name):
    name_list = full_name.split()
    initials = ''
    for name in name_list:
        initials += name[0]

    if initials not in unique:
        unique.append(initials)
        return initials
    else:
        initials = ''
        i=0
        for name in name_list:
            if i==0:
                initials += name[:2]
                i +=1
            else:
                initials += name[0]
        return initials

Skills['Initials'] = Skills['Name'].apply(lambda x: unique_initials(x))
```